# Server has Half GBIT when it's the IPERF server including Client except when Client is IPERF server

Tags: linux, windows, networking, iperf

**First of all: NO, it isn't any of the cables, switch or network cards of my two systems. Everything in this setup is 1GBIT and it used to work. And no it isn't the speed of my storage.**

*My Server which was running Windows Server 2019 had no type of issues like this, it all started when I installed Debian with no GUI on my server, and noticed my upload speed with SMB (Windows -> Linux) was cut in half.*

**Server Specs (if you can even call the hardware server grade)**

```
CPU: AMD A6-7400K @ 3.5GHz
RAM: Generic 8GB DDR3 RAM (Works fine though)
Motherboard: Gigabyte F2A78M-HD2 (Rev 3.1)

Storage:
Toshiba Acer 160GB Drive (Has the OS on it)
Seagate 250GB Drive + Hitachi 250GB Drive (RAID0, yes this is dumb)

OS: Debian x64 with no GUI (Latest version, already did apt full-upgrade and all thoses things)
```

Long story short: When running SMB or even IPERF:

**Windows Client (as IPERF server):** Both the Linux and Windows machine are at **1GBIT**

Image of the Output Terminal of the Linux Server showing what I expect:

[image]

**Linux Server (as IPERF server):** Both Linux and Windows machines are capped at **half a GBIT**
Image of the Output Terminal of the Linux Server showing that the speed is cutted by roughly a half:

[image]

What even is going on there?
I don't even know what to point except Debian.

EDIT: Tried attempts at fixing this:

Checking and Installing Realtek Firmware (non free thing), Custom Kernel with 1000hz timer

Comment: Could this be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1802691 ?

Comment: Doesn't seem related.

Comment: I think at this point I'm dead ass gonna reinstall Windows Server cause this is unusable.